# How to Connect Remote Database in Laravel 5 using ssh

Tags: php, laravel, ssh

I am using Laravel 5.0. I Want to Know How to Access Remote Database using SSH.

database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'www.xxxxx.in',
            'port' => '2222',
            'database'  => 'xxxx_xxx',
            'username'  => 'xxxxx_xx',
            'password'  => 'xxxx0xx',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
            'engine'    => null,
        ],
```

Comment: I am interested in the answer to this question. Not only for the Laravel scenario but for others as well

Answer (score 8):

You should create SSH tunnel.

More about SSH tunnel and some examples here:
http://chxo.com/be2/20040511_5667.html

Example:

```
ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 myuser@remotehost.com
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u dbuser -p db
```

Of course, then you need to change credentials:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'www.xxxxx.in',
            'port'      => '3307',
            'database'  => 'xxxx_xxx',
            ...
        ],
```

Comment: I am looking for a good answer to point duplicates of this question to - this would be it, but the config shown is wrong, and will confuse ppl who are asking this question. 
 I suggest `www.xxxxx.in` should be changed here to `127.0.0.1` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create an SSH Tunnel [as Alexey says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36034966/393021).

You will also need to port-forward the MySQL connection port to your local; as Alexey has done also.

Then in your Laravel config, set the port to the forwarded port. So building off Alexey's answer, your database configuration would read thus

```
'mysql' => [
      'driver'    => 'mysql',
      'host'      => 'www.xxxxx.in',
      'port'      => '3307',
      'database'  => 'xxxx_xxx',
      'username'  => 'xxxxx_xx',
      'password'  => 'xxxx0xx',
      'charset'   => 'utf8',
      'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
      'prefix'    => '',
      'strict'    => false,
      'engine'    => null,
],
```

**EDIT**
In case Alexey's answer goes away, these are the relevant parts to my answer

Create the ssh tunnel

```
ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 myuser@remotehost.com
```

Connect locally using

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u dbuser -p db
```